# Switch to SQL Sever database for jBPM 7 with Spring Boot

Tags: jbpm, jta

I have created an app from https://start.jbpm.org/, it works fine with H2.

Now I want to switch to SQL Sever. It gives below error during startup

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not commit session or rollback
    at org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.rollbackTransaction(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[jbpm-human-task-jpa-7.30.0.Final.jar:7.30.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.execute(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:108) ~[jbpm-human-task-jpa-7.30.0.Final.jar:7.30.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.execute(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:49) ~[jbpm-human-task-jpa-7.30.0.Final.jar:7.30.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39) ~[drools-core-7.30.0.Final.jar:7.30.0.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jta.TransactionLockInterceptor.execute(TransactionLockInterceptor.java:73) ~[drools-persistence-api-7.30.0.Final.jar:7.30.0.Final]
```

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://10.111.88.10:3341;DatabaseName=JBPM_7
spring.datasource.username=lo2
spring.datasource.password=ta
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jta.narayana.transaction-manager-id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issues is with JTA, not getting SQL Server to run.

To address using SQL Server first, you need install the SQL Server driver.  This is available from Microsoft.  Currently, they package several drivers in one archive so you need to install the right one.

Second, you need to change your datasource (or create a new one) to use SQL Server.

Third, you need to alter the Hibernate configuration.

From the above it looks like you have SQL Server running with Hibernate but have an issue with JTA transactions.  The configuration files include JNDI for using JTA for container-managed transactions.  I, for simplicity, employ user-managed transactions under JTA with JDBC:

```
try {
  txn = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
  txn.begin();
...
  txn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                txn.rollback();
...

The lookup changes for container-managed transaction.  I am adding a JTA tag so people can expand on my answer.
```